# NS_ENUM in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums, compiler-errors, objective-c-swift-bridge

**NOTE**: This is not a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34069507/3398839).

I am trying to use a library named [GBCli](https://github.com/tomaz/GBCli) in Swift. It was written in Objective-C. I am having trouble with a particular enum:

```
/** Various command line argument value requirements. */
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, GBValueFlags) {
    GBValueRequired, ///< Command line argument requires a value.
    GBValueOptional, ///< Command line argument can optionally have a value, but is not required.
    GBValueNone ///< Command line argument is on/off switch.
};
```

I am trying to use the method:

```
- (void)registerOption:(NSString *)longOption shortcut:(char)shortOption requirement:(GBValueRequirements)requirement;
```

In the documentation, a suggested use is:

```
[parser registerOption:@"verbose" shortcut:'v' requirement:GBValueRequired];
```

I tried translating this as:

```
parser.registerOption("verbose", shortcut: 118 /* Array("v".utf8)[0] */, requirement: .Required);
```

**Note**: It seems that `GBValueRequirements` is the argument type used by the library, but that `GBValueFlag` is the actual type that they intend you to pass into said methods. Evidence: `typedef NSUInteger GBValueRequirements;`, the enum mentioned above, and the fact that many functions take a `GBValueRequirements`. Also note that each case in `GBValueFlags` is exclusive, so they are not meant to be OR'ed together.

However, that gives an error of `Type 'UInt' has no member 'Required'`, which doesn't make sense seeing that the the enum was defined to be of type `NSUInteger` (which should translate to UInt). I am able to access GBValueFlags, but I am unable to see whatever swift translated it to. Strangely, this works:

```
let requiredTest : GBValueFlags = .Required;
```

But this doesn't:

```
parser.registerOption("verbose", shortcut: 118 /* Array("v".utf8)[0] */, requirement: requiredTest);
```

Because it throws:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'GBValueFlags' to expected argument type 'UInt'
```

at compile time. How should I pass the equivalent of `.Required` to the method?

Defining my own enum won't work because the internal code of GBCli checks the argument against its own enum.

Comment: How about `parser.registerOption("verbose", shortcut: 118 /* Array("v".utf8)[0] */, requirement: GBValueFlags.Required.rawValue)`?

Comment: @JonBrooks THANK YOU!!! Post as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this (though it's not pretty):

```
parser.registerOption("verbose", shortcut: 118 /* Array("v".utf8)[0] */, requirement: GBValueFlags.Required.rawValue)
```